# Encrypting many PDFs by python using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, encryption, permissions, pypdf

I am trying to make a python program which loops through all files in a folder, selects those which have extension '.pdf', and encrypt them with restricted permissions. I am using this version of PyPDF2 library:
https://github.com/vchatterji/PyPDF2. (A modification of the original PyPDF2 which also allows to set permissions). I have tested it with a single pdf file and it works fine. I want that the original pdf file should be deleted and the encrypted one should remain with the same name.
Here is my code:

```
import os
import PyPDF2

directory = './'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"): 
        pdfFile = open(filename, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
        pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))
        pdfFile.close()
        os.remove(filename)
        pdfWriter.encrypt('', 'ispat', perm_mask=-3904)
        resultPdf = open(filename, 'wb')
        pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)
        resultPdf.close()
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

It gives the following error:

```
  C:\Users\manul\Desktop\ghh>python encrypter.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypter.py", line 9, in <module>
  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
  File "C:\Users\manul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1153, in __init__
  self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\manul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1758, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have some PDFs stored in 'ghh' folder on Desktop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the PyPDF2 source code and don't see any problems with the way you're doing things (or what it does). All I can suggest is that since `PdfFileReader` will also accept a file name as an argument, that you try passing it `filename` instead of opening the file yourself (It will close it for you).

Answer (score 0):

Using `pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename)` will make the reader work, but this specific error is caused by your files being empty. You can check the file sizes with `os.path.getsize(filename)`. Your files were probably wiped because the script deletes the original file, then creates a new file with `open(filepath, "wb")`, and then it terminates incorrectly due to an error that occurs with `pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)`, leaving an empty file with the original file name.

Passing a file name instead of a file object to `PdfFileReader` as mentioned resolves the error that occurs with `pdfWriter` (I don't know why), but you'll need to replace any empty files in your directory with copies of the original pdfs to get rid of the OSError.